# derivation on K(X,Y)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the notion of a derivation in abstract algebra.

On wikipedia it is written that the derivation is defined over an algebra.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28differential_algebra%29

I don't understand why this is the case.
Wouldn't it be possible to define it over the field?

For instance, If I'm working in $K(X)$ where $K$ is a field,
why can't I say that $D$ is a map from $K(X)$ to $K(X)$ which satisfies the Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can. The definition is just more general than that. If you just want $D: K(X)\to K(X)$ such that $D$ is additive and $D(ab) = aD(b) + D(a)b$, then it is a derivation of $K(X)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

If furthermore you want $D$ to be $K$-linear, then it is a derivation of $K(X)$ as a $K$-algebra.

It is never a restriction to work with $R$-algebras rather than rings, since a ring is the same thing as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

Comment: What adavantage do I have if I define $D$ to be K-linear rather than Z-linear?